# isotope transform translate position is wrong

Tags: html, css, jquery-isotope

please [see the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QsCZx/13/) there is the green box which should be right next to the blue box but it doesn't work if I add width:200px; on the blue boxes.

[image]

```
<div class="item green">transform: translate (285px, 3px) NOT (307px, 3px)</div>
```

if the blue box hasn't got a width:200px; it works all fine http://jsfiddle.net/QsCZx/14/

[image]

anyone had the same issues before? any easy way to fix this?

thanks for help and advices

Comment: @rednaw to see what it does you have to resize the viewport. more about isotope here: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/ removing $container.isotope... is not an option

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in   Isotope v1.5.25    , in the unminified version in `jquery.isotope.js` go to line around 601 and replace

```
x = Math.round( x + this.offset.left );
```

with:

```
x = Math.round( x );
```